Docker build is not pushed to container registry for guardrails package
In my python application I am using detect_pii and provenance_embeddings lib from guardrails-ai.It is working as expected.
Now I created a Docker file and has written a github action workflow to build the docker image and push it to a container registry.
While building the docker image during the installation of detect_pii and provenance_embeddings I got several issues and found that it is because of numpy version.Now the installation is correct , image is built but image is not getting pushed to container registry .I am getting below error while the image is being written to layers.

#16 preparing build cache for export
#16 writing layer sha256:081a3493c0e761c11da41712a3b88b1fe8be04136a1dcb26c8f44c4b2433633e done
#16 writing layer sha256:0b61b7b259eb3d2247ad58d1a46d5db155a8db279900e911a6cd824168cc53e4
#16 writing layer sha256:0b61b7b259eb3d2247ad58d1a46d5db155a8db279900e911a6cd824168cc53e4 0.2s done
#16 writing layer sha256:3c5caa9a28e74de53b117107558107449522110aa9a695f26328c4cccf95b48a
#16 writing layer sha256:3c5caa9a28e74de53b117107558107449522110aa9a695f26328c4cccf95b48a done
#16 writing layer sha256:40d734479f1486a126c248a001290d9d4fcb6c6f2018c508a91125938bf3404c 0.0s done
#16 writing layer sha256:99ab3df87e74d15b2c7da222bbac7c0cdc0a3858579982e9f4de3840bac84134
#16 preparing build cache for export 38.3s done
#16 writing layer sha256:99ab3df87e74d15b2c7da222bbac7c0cdc0a3858579982e9f4de3840bac84134 38.0s done
#16 ERROR: error writing layer blob: failed to copy: failed to send write: write /tmp/.buildx-cache/ingest/44eca930b84e16fa67395824aedec982c33ef3311b274e4f983910dbfc7fb179/data: no space left on device: unknown
------
 > exporting cache to client directory:
------
WARNING: local cache import at /tmp/.buildx-cache not found due to err: could not read /tmp/.buildx-cache/index.json: open /tmp/.buildx-cache/index.json: no such file or directory
ERROR: failed to solve: error writing layer blob: failed to copy: failed to send write: write /tmp/.buildx-cache/ingest/44eca930b84e16fa67395824aedec982c33ef3311b274e4f983910dbfc7fb179/data: no space left on device: unknown
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: error writing layer blob: failed to copy: failed to send write: write /tmp/.buildx-cache/ingest/44eca930b84e16fa67395824aedec982c33ef3311b274e4f983910dbfc7fb179/data: no space left on device: unknown


Docker file I am using

# Stage 1: Builder stage
FROM python:3.11-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /app

# Copy requirements file
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install build dependencies and Python dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libffi-dev \
    git && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    guardrails hub install hub://guardrails/detect_pii && \
    guardrails hub install hub://guardrails/provenance_embeddings && \
    apt-get purge -y build-essential git && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /root/.cache

# Stage 2: Runtime stage
FROM python:3.11-slim AS runtime

WORKDIR /app

# Copy Python dependencies and binaries from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Set environment variables
ENV APP_USER=myuser
ENV HOME=/home/${APP_USER}
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

# Install gunicorn
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir gunicorn

# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run Gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "guniconfig:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "--workers", "4", "--threads", "4"]


What changes shall I do in docker or my github action workflow yaml?

Can you please show us your requirements.txt?
